# Is The subspace of $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb C)$ consisting of all matrices of rank equal to $k$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Let $m ,n$  be positive integers and $0 \leq k \leq \min \{m,n\}$ an integer.
>
> Prove or disprove:
> The subspace of $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb C)$ consisting of all matrices of rank equal to $k$ is connected.

How should I start the problem

Answer (score 3):

Hint : use the following result.

> A matrix $M\in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{C})$ is of rank $k$ if and only if there exists $(A,B)\in GL_m(\mathbb{C})\times  GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that :
>
> $$AMB=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&...&...&...&...&0\\0&1&0&...&...&...&0\\\vdots&0&\ddots &0&...&...&\vdots\\ &&&1&\ddots\\0&&...&&0&...&0\\\vdots&&&&&&\vdots\\0&&...&&&...&0\end{pmatrix}$$
>
> i.e. a matrix with $k$ ones on its diagonal and $0$ everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will be yes.  One strategy of proof is to find a path from a rank-$k$ matrix in Jordan form to the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{I_{k\times k}&0\\0&0}
$$

Comment: In fact, if you've heard of the [Weyr form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyr_canonical_form) of a matrix, using this instead of Jordan form makes things a little bit easier.

Comment: What would be a path from $\left[\matrix{1 & 0\\0 & 1}\right]$ to $\left[\matrix{1 & 0\\0 & -1}\right]$ in matrices of rank $2$?

Comment: @A.G *complex* matrices of rank 2. Multiply $-1$ by $e^{it}$.

Comment: Ok, have missed *complex*.